# Possible to use globbing for grunt `dest`?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, glob

Is it possible to use globbing to specify a `dest` property of a grunt task? E.g.:

```
dev: {
    src: './src/**/*.html',
    dest: './build/dev/**/*.html'
}
```

instead of:

```
dev: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: './src/',
    src: ['**/*.html'],
    dest: './build/dev/',
    ext: '.html'
}
```

I ask because I'd like to use `dev.src` in a template elsewhere in my Gruntfile, so if there's a different way to do that via `grunt.file.expand` I'm interested in that too.